# Send notifications to individual users using Azure Mobile Services with custom API

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, windows-phone-8, push-notification

I hope to **send notifications to individual users** using Azure Mobile Services. When I add the notification service in Visual Studio 2013, it automatically generate a custom API in my Azure service. Since I have built my mobile service with JavaScript backend. The generate code is follow:

```
exports.post = function (request, response) {
    response.send(statusCodes.OK);
    sendNotifications(request);
};


function sendNotifications(request) {
    var payload = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><toast><visual><binding template="ToastText01">' +
    '<text id="1">' + request.body.toast + '</text></binding></visual></toast>';
    var push = request.service.push;

push.wns.send(null,
    payload,
    'wns/toast', {
        success: function (pushResponse) {
            console.log("Sent push:", pushResponse);
        }
    });
}
```

And In my client service, I have used userId as my tags and invoke the function

```
 `await App.MobileService.GetPush().RegisterNativeAsync(channel.Uri,userIdTags);`
```

where userIdTags is a List of strings that contains certain userId values I hope to receive the message.

But when I debug I found that **all of users will receive the notification.** So I would like to know whether do I need to handle or modify the auto-generate code in the custom API or any other reason that cause the problem .

Comment: I think you've done what you an do on client side and you need to update your mobile service script. What you want to do is similar to the [Send push notifications to authenticated users](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-windows-universal-dotnet-get-started-users/). So check the concept in the blog.

Comment: If it still work since I use my custom authentication but not any of authentication ways that Microsoft offers?

Comment: Sorry, I found I provided a wrong link to you. Check [this](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-windows-store-dotnet-push-notifications-app-users/). and I don't think the authentication way matters